How to make this specific layout circular menu with HTML CSS?
I would like to make this menu in pure HTML and CSS or something with Javascript.
I tried using some alternatives using a container and modifying its borders, but I didn't get a decent and desired result. Let's say I'm not the best guy in HTML/CSS
This is how I would like it to look example If anyone can help me with this I would be extremely grateful.
The closest I got to the result was this, but I can't make any progress, and I don't think this is ideal because as I'm going to align items on the edges, I don't know what else to do to get the result in the example.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dynamic path</title>
    <style>
        body, html {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .half-circle {
            width: 100px;
            height: 200px;
            border-top-left-radius: 100px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 100px;
            border: 10px solid gray;
            border-right: 0;

            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="half-circle"></div>
</body>
</html>



I tried an approach using borders in a container as you can see in the code block I mentioned above

This should be easier with some svg, like this example : https://codepen.io/Thijs/pen/yyRBxV

But with this example I don't understand how I'm going to make a personalized shape as I need
